# make error latex

Tags: makefile, latex

```
make -C doc html latexpdf
```

yields this:

```
Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/hypcap.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty)
Writing index file Arakoon.idx
(./Arakoon.aux)
Runaway argument?
{{1.10.3}{9}{Client side support\relax }{subsection.1.10.
! File ended while scanning use of \@newl@bel.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.113 \begin{document}

?
```

Comment: Why do you keep posting with empty "BLOCKQUOTE" sections at the top and bottom, that we have to edit for you?

Comment: This is a `LaTeX` error, not a `make` error. You should try to make a [`minimal example`](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that replicates the problem. Also, this kind of question is better suited over at [`tex.stackexchange.com`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The same qn was asked at tex.sx (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93748/latex-error-during-make) - I've answered here rather than there, because that has been closed.

Answer (score 8):

If someone is still looking for this: For me usually, when a prior build had failed due to an error, subsequent builds would fail with this error. Solved it by deleting the main `.aux` file and building it again.

Comment: This is a big LaTeX compiling bug: once the error is corrected, the compilation keeps outputting an error :´(. Thanks for posting, if you hadn't, I had wasted long time debugging: +1!

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to say with any confidence, but it looks like a fragile (non-robust) command in a subsubsection heading or a maths label (would be label 10.1.3), because:

1. It occurs at `\begin{document}`, when the .aux files are loaded,
2. The error indicates a malformed directive in the .aux file, and the presence of a `\relax` there - typically what command reduce to after having performed their side effect.

Two suggestions:

1. Generate an MWE by making a new document from this with all the body of your document except that heading/ equation (and perhaps the sentence following) deleted.  Does this create the same error?  If so, post it here.  You might need some trial and error to find out which Lat3ex command is responsible, but it should contain the text `Client side support`.
2. Do read https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands - if I am right, you have a fragile command where it shouldn't be.  Figure out what should be there instead.